# Global objects in C# ASP.Net - always null when read back

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, global

In an ASP.Net project, using C#, I have a class (PlcComms.cs) for talking to a Controller (a PLC).
I want the one class object to be globally available, for each web page in my project.

I see from reading various forum posts that I should be able to create a public static object of my class type, i.e. PlcComms, in Global.asax.cs, or in a class in the App_Code folder.  I've tried both and I write to the object ok, but when I go to read from it (from a timer in an update panel on the home web page) then it always read back as null.

**I'm at a loss to know what to do at this point.  can anyone help?**

Currently, this is a class I have in the App_Code folder...

```
namespace SpearheadWeb
{
    public static class AppGlobal
    {
        public static SpearheadWeb.PlcComms PlcCommsObject { get; set; }
    }
}
```

this I have on my web page - it seems to create the object OK...

```
namespace SpearheadWeb
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        private PlcComms CurrentPLC;
        //some other here including ComPorts

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                try
                {
                    //some settings reading and setup here
                    CurrentPLC = new PlcComms(Global.CommsSettings.CpuType1,Global.CommsSettings.Network1,ComPorts[0], Global.CommsSettings.IPAddress1, Global.CommsSettings.Path1,UpdatePanel.Controls[0].Controls, 1, Global.CommsSettings.MsUpdate1);

                    AppGlobal.PlcCommsObject = CurrentPLC;
```

but in my timer (the timer within an updatepanel) PLCComms1 is always null here...

```
        protected void TimerUpdate_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PlcComms PLCComms1 = AppGlobal.PlcCommsObject;
```

Comment: Is it possible the `Page_Load` isn't getting passed the reading/construction step? the catch of the try/catch is hidden so I don't know if maybe that's getting smothered out - that would explain why it's not setting the `AppGlobal.PlcCommsObject`

Comment: I don't think it's related to your problem, but it seems weird that you create a new CurrentPLC each time the page loads. I thought you wanted just one of these?

Comment: the class members (vars defined before code in the class) do NOT persist. when the page is rendered and then sent down to client side? Each timer fire will now do a post back and the whole page + class is recreated from scratch each time. You need to grasp the concept of lifecycle for a page. The class is re-created every time for post back. Web development is state-less. So, you can't use the web form class to persist values - they simply do not. So a static class can't persist any values, except during the page render - and then it sent back down client side. (and class goes out of scope).

Comment: Mike Fisher: Yes, creating CurrentPLC in the page code is a bit odd, but anyway I though copying it to AppGlobal.PlcCommsObject you mean that it would persist outside of the page, as read by the timer.

Comment: **Albert D. Kallal**:  Thanks.  Yes, I understand that class members on the page do not persist.  The timer in the updatepanel means the timer does not call the post back, as I understand it, but that doens't help much.  So, where can I create the a public PlcComms class object that will persist and can be read by a number of pages, each with their timer, at a later time?

Comment: **slorello**: Thanks.  It is setting the `AppGlobal.PlcCommsObject`, it's just not persisting.

Comment: Application or Session possibly. You could set values in Global.asax.

Comment: **wazz**: Yes, I tried public variables in Global.asax but that didn't seem to work, the same effect, read back as null